# Access class property from a function defined in its prototype

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn OOP JavaScript concepts. Below is the code of my class:

```
var Dialog = function(selector, properties) {
  this.dialog = $(selector);
  this.isVisible = false;

  this.build(selector, settings);
};
Dialog.prototype.build = function(selector, settings) {
  var dialogContent = this.dialog.html();
  dialog.empty();
};
```

This is how I initialize the class:

```
var dialog1 = new Dialog(".dialog", {
  title: "Confirm",
  modal: false,
  buttons: [
    ["cancel", "cancelButton", "No"],
    ["accept", "acceptButton", "Yes"]
  ]
});
```

The console reports that `dialog` is undefined. How can I access the `dialog` variable?

See my entire file `dialog.js` [here](http://pastebin.com/0SNLmJkw)

**P.S.** I am currently reading the MDN Documentation, but I don't realize where I am wrong in my code. I have also tried replacing `this.build()` with `this.build.call(this, /*..*/)`, but no result.

Comment: You're using `properties` in one place, `settings` in another (within `Dialog`). Are they meant to be the same?

Comment: *"The console reports that dialog is undefined. How can i access the dialog variable?"* In what code? `build`? What you have in `build` (`this.dialog`) would be fine, if it weren't for the above issue with using an undeclared variable (`settings`).

Comment: The settings is declared. I have posted only the code relevant for solving my problem. The error from the console seems to be on line 21 (as the Console says), which is, in my file, the line with `var dialogContent = //...`

Comment: See my entire file `dialog.js` here: http://pastebin.com/0SNLmJkw

Comment: *"See my entire file dialog.js here: pastebin.com/0SNLmJkw"* No, content for the question goes *in* the question. (The minimum necessary.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think it's OK to place the relevant code in the question, and other extra stuff in a link.

Comment: @Scimonster: But the relevant code *isn't* in the question.

Comment: It is, because the error was on this line `var dialogContent = this.dialog.html();`

Comment: And yet the answer you accepted shows the error being with code you didn't provide. "Relevant code" means the code should be sufficient to reproduce the issue you're describing. Links to other sites are not a substitute for including all relevant code directly in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your code, line 21:

```
dialog.empty()
```

You can't do that. You always need to have `this` in front of it.

```
this.dialog.empty()
```

Answer (score 2):

In the [full pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0SNLmJkw) that you posted, you're not actually using `this.dialog`. You're using:

```
var dialogContent = Dialog.prototype.dialog.html();
```

Naturally, the prototype isn't going to have the `dialog` property. If you switch that to `this.dialog`, it should work fine.